# Distinct valúes while using multiple joins

Tags: sql-server

I want to obtain one single row but it is returning 3 rows. The form_audit table has 3 rows with the same REF_NO,
How to get one distinct row?

[image]

Comment: If you want only one record you can try `TOP`, if your question is why `DISTINCT` is returning multiple rows. Then some of the columns must be having a different value.

`SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 [the rest of the Query]`

Comment: Which is the field(s) returned from your query that is not a duplicate(s) / has different data per record? How would you determine which of these values you wish to show, or do you not care, so long as you show one?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will give you some idea how it works

```
CREATE TABLE #tblBackers (
amountBacked MONEY, 
backersAccountID INT,
playerBacked INT,
Dates DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,12345,99999,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,12345,99999,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,12345,99699,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,12345,99999,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,98765,88888,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO #tblBackers VALUES (25,76543,77777,GETDATE())

GO

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #tblBackers

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 * FROM #tblBackers
```

And use the `ORDER BY` to get the latest record.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one record per `ref_no`, then consider adding a [`group by`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) clause on that field.

```
select 
    fa.ref_no
    /*, other stuff*/
from
    FORM_AUDIT fa
    /* other joins*/
group by
    fa.ref_no;
```

Keep in mind that this `group by` clause will aggregate all records that share the same `ref_no` into a single record in the result set. That means that you can no longer include fields like `fh.*` and `fcd.*` in the select list directly, because you have no guarantee that each of those fields has only one value per row in your result set. For every such field that you want to include in your select list, you must either:

- Include that field in your `group by` clause, keeping in mind that doing so will no longer necessarily give you exactly one row per distinct `ref_no`; now you'll get one row per distinct combination of `ref_no` and whatever else you add to the `group by` clause, or
- Use one of SQL Server's [aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql) to transform the set of zero-to-many values in the field you're adding into a single value. Aggregate functions are things like `max()`, `sum()`, `count()`, etc. There's a complete list at the link.

Good luck!